# Boost and expire not working after update

Tags: caching

big problem here. I have a website up from 2 years and working with combo of **boost cache** system and **expire** to handle clear cache on insert/modify or delete Node.

Two days ago I did upgrade of this two modules (first tested locally properly to see if generated errors). I did not realize that there is an issue when the nodes were inserted expire cache was not working. Ergo now every time the editor of the site inserted nodes **must clear the cache manually**.

Drupal **not write error** or warning in log. Does anyone have this problem? Any idea about? Thanks a lot guys.
More info:

- Drupal 7.36
- Boost 7.x-1.0
- Expire 7.x-2.0-rc4

Comment: Did you check to see if the Expire settings are set to enable a cache expiration upon a **Node Insert**?

Comment: Yes, it is configured for exipre on insert/modify/delete node. Settings is the same as always. Before module's update everything worked well.